# Execute javascript function before defining

Tags: javascript, function

I have a simple javascript function that should be place in the  section:

```
<script>
function b() {

}
</script>
```

And this simple one in the  section:

```
<script>
function a() {
   b();
}
</script>
```

When trying to call function b from function a I get an undefined function b as it's defined after function a. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Can you post valid JavaScript?

Comment: Why don't you just define `b` first?  Or wait until it's defined before calling `a`?

Comment: `function b();` is not valid JavaScript. Do you need a time machine here? It's completely unclear why you would want to do this. What about `$(function() { b() })` to only run `b()` when the document is fully loaded?

Comment: sorry corrected the mistake

Comment: Try creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) replicating your issue. That will help people debug your issue.

Comment: Put the both function definitions into a same script tag, then automatic hoisting will solve the problem. Or rather do what Rocket has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if u wrote it wrong or is the error u are having but try:

```
<script>
function a() {
    b();
}
</script>
```

Comment: @MichaelSamuel - That is working fine. The problem is something else you are not mentioning then. The order in which they appear in the script tag does not matter as long as they are bound inside of separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

The order does not matter. Instead look at your call of `function b();`.

To call a function just specify the function's name so you would say `b();`.

```
<script>
    function a() {
        b();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: the order of inline script certainly does matter, especially when using inline calls.

Comment: Of course it matters the order you call something (inside of a function) but the order in which your functions are placed in the script tag does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Either the answer above, or:

Why not just make a javascript file and call the functions in your html?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        a();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the javascript file would be something like:

```
function a () {
    b();
}
function b () {
}
```